# How to Change the Package of a Maven Plug-in With Testing Harness

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I used [this tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html) to create a very basic setup to create and test a Maven mojo. The two classes look something like this.

**Mojo:**

```
/**
 * @goal touch
 * @phase process-sources
 */
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class MyMojoTest {
    @Rule
    public MojoRule rule = new MojoRule();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        File pom = new File("src/test/resources/pom.xml");
        MyMojo myMojo = (MyMojo) rule.lookupMojo("touch", pom);
        Assert.assertNotNull(myMojo);
        myMojo.execute();
    }
}
```

It works so far. Then I moved it to my own project, to see why my tests wouldn't work. It still worked until I moved the classes into another package.

The default is `org.apache.maven.plugin.my` and I'm not sure if that is somehow forced for all Maven plug-ins or taken from some weird property I can't figure out.

Properties that don't contribute to this package are:

- pom's artifact ID
- pom's group ID
- pom's version

The error message is:

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
  roleHint: org.acme:maven-my-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:touch
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:240)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusTestCase.lookup(PlexusTestCase.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupMojo(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupMojo(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.MojoRule.lookupMojo(MojoRule.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.my.MyMojoTest.testSomething(MyMojoTest.java:22)
```

So how do I change the package? `org.apache.maven.plugin.my` sounds really tutorially.

Comment: A Mojo can have any package. The exception says it cannot find the goal `convert-phar` for the plugin with groupId `org.acm`, artifactId `maven-my-plugin`and version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` ( and please change the artifactId to something like my-maven-plugin, plugins that start with maven are considered to be maintained by the Apache Maven team.)

Comment: @RobertScholte These are to represent my Maven plug-in's GAV coordinates. The goal was a copying error. From the exception it looks like the testing harness looks for the right plug-in and goal.

Comment: Are you running tests via IDE or commandline? In case of IDE it might be that the plugin descriptor wasn't created  or is still invalid. It is created at `target/classes/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml`. Most important elements: plugin.groupId/artifactId/version and mojo.goal/implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bunch of stupid mistakes why my mojos (including the above one) won't work, like:

- Maven mojos don't get compiled automatically like Java files, you need to start Maven manually (or use somthing like *Maven -> Update Project* in your IDE)
- I imported `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test`, so the `MojoRule` was not initialized correctly